# Jenkins - summarising test result changes from XUnit

Tags: jenkins, nunit, xunit, email-ext

I'm running NUnit tests using Jenkins (and the XUnit plugin), and Email-Ext to send out build result summaries.

I'd like to be able to email out something like "3 new test failures: [Names of tests that failed]." I can't work out how to get which tests changed from a previous run.

So far I have:

```
${TEST_COUNTS,var="total"} tests: ${TEST_COUNTS,var="pass"} pass,
${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"} fail, ${TEST_COUNTS,var="skip"} skipped
```

giving
`1914 tests: 1903 pass, 10 fail, 1 skipped`

and `${FAILED_TESTS}` giving the details of all tests failing - but I can't work out how to get just the changes from the previous run.

Viewing the job in Jenkins gives the information I need, so it ought to be possible.

Comment: I think a Jelly script email template for the [Email-ext+plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) is the way to go. The [example script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/text.jelly) lead me to [PackageResult](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/tasks/junit/PackageResult.html) → [TestObject.getHistory()](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/tasks/test/TestObject.html#getHistory%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

============================

## TESTS

There are ${TEST_COUNTS, var="total"} total tests of which ${TEST_COUNTS, var="fail"} test(s) failed. 
$FAILED_TESTS

Comment: I was specifically looking for what had changed from the previous build, *not* all failed tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

CHANGES (All changes since first failure)

```
${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS, reverse=true}
```